# SPARQL query with one mandatory filter and one optional filter

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to run a SPARQL query against Wikidata that has one filter which is required and one filter which is optional.  I keep getting malformed query errors.  This query, without the Optional line, **runs without issue**:

```
SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.
  ?person wdt:P27 ?citizenshipCountry.
  ?person wdt:P19/wdt:P17 ?birthCountry.
  filter(?citizenshipCountry = wd:Q30 || ?birthCountry = wd:Q30)
  }
```

When I try to add the optional filter, I get malformed query errors:

```
SELECT ?person WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P106 wd:Q82955.
  ?person wdt:P27 ?citizenshipCountry.
  ?person wdt:P19/wdt:P17 ?birthCountry.
  filter(?citizenshipCountry = wd:Q30 || ?birthCountry = wd:Q30)
  OPTIONAL: filter(!bound(?dob) || ?dob > "1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
  }
```

I know the syntax of the Optional line itself is ok, as I've used that separately in other queries where it's the only filter.

Comment: The optional line is actually not ok. The optional part needs to be in curly brackets {}.
Secondly, the variable ?dob does not appear anywhere in the query, so !BOUND(?dob) = true always.

Comment: What you need is something like this, (using wdt:P569 for date of birth):
https://w.wiki/vys assuming you are looking for people regardless of their dob, and for their dob also if after 1979.

Comment: Hi, no this is not what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for people who were either born after 1979 OR their profile does not contain a date of birth at all.  That's what I thought OPTIONAL was used for - to ensure that when a given field is blank, it still returns the profile.

Comment: In this case you need a UNION statement, because you don't want to see people like Napoleon Bonaparte, whose dob is known, but before 1980.

Comment: This query shows you how: https://w.wiki/v$8

Comment: Thanks for your continued help - can you take a look at this https://w.wiki/v$c - here I've incorporated your example into mine, but to test that the dob filter is working correctly, I've temporarily removed the `UNION` statement. This query returns no results.  I would expect for example Jared Kushner to be returned because he meets all the criteria and was definitely born after 1970.  What am I doing wrong this time? :)

Comment: your should use `xsd:dateTime` instead: `?person wdt:P569 ?dob .
  hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true .
  FILTER (?dob > "1970-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime)`

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks so much.  Can you tell me a little bit more about the `hint` statements?  I was able to run the query successfully without those parts and still get expected results..

Comment: @UninformedUser never mind, I finally found the explanation on Wikidata.  Thanks again!

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot - it just helps the query optimizer and makes query execution possible faster as it can make use of database indexes. By the way, don't forget to provide an answer here and also accept your own answer. This will help others have similar issues.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks!